# how to apply css rule to first div matching class

Tags: css

I want to apply some css to a div element matching a class name, but there will multiple matches and only want to apply it to the second occurrence of this match.

The divs could be in any part of the body/html tree

I have tried this:

div[class*='id-type__']

Here is a simplified version of the html tree, please note the divs could be anywhere I have no control of this and the only common pattern is the class has a value 'id-type__'

```html
  <div>
     <span>
        <div class="id-type__">
          <span></span>
        </div>
     </span>
  </div>
  <div class="id-type__">
      <span>
        <div class="id-type__">
          <span></span>
        </div>
      </span>
  </div>
```

What i want to do is only apply css to the second occurrence of where i find div[class*='id-type__']

Comment: Can you just add another class?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:nth-child()` selector.

```css
div:nth-child(2){
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <span>
        <div>
          <span>Content</span>
        </div>
     </span>
  </div>
  <div>
      <span>
        <div>
          <span>Content</span>
        </div>
      </span>
  </div>
```